# Partitioned memory for writing a soft CPU of virtual machine

Tags: c, memory, cpu-registers

I'm trying to write a simple soft CPU in C that will work on an imaginary machine for an embedded application. I'm new to this, so bear with me.

I've been trying to do this in an IDE, but run into an issue where I need to malloc the memory and am not getting a consistent memory address for allocating my registers, so I'm unable to run tests and debug. On an actual piece of hardware, I understand that the documentation would give me the addresses of specific registers, main memory, and hard disk memory, correct? I'd like to be able to define macros for my registers that I can then pass around to read/write, but this seems impossible without static memory addresses.

So it seems like I need a good way to allocate a static chunk of memory with static addresses, either in an IDE or on my own machine with a text editor. What would be the best way to do this? For reference, I'm using Cloud9 IDE but can't figure out how to do it in this platform.

Thanks!

Comment: You're thinking it wrong... code running ON your virtual CPU might need fixed adresses for I/O registers and the like. Your code is supposed to *translate* addresses. E.g. for RAM, you could just use them as offset into a chunk allocated with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like `uint8_t* const address_space = calloc( memory_size, sizeof(uint8_t) );`, check the return value of course, and then make all your machine addresses indices into the array, like `address_space[dest] = register[src];`.  If your emulated CPU can handle data of different sizes or has less strict alignment restrictions than your host CPU, you would need to use `memcpy()` or pointer casts to transfer data.

Your debugger will understand expressions like `address_space[i]` whether `address_space` is statically or dynamically allocated, but you can statically allocate it if you know the exact size in advance, such as to emulate a machine with 16-bit addresses that always has exactly 65,536 bytes of RAM.

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't realize I could just treat a chunk of malloc'd memory like an array. Thanks!